# How should you populate an entity (bean) object property when the property value comes from a reference table?

Tags: oop, object, architecture, entity, domain-driven-design

Lets say you have an entity object called `Business` with properties like `businessID`,`businessName`,`entityType`, and `entityTypeName`. With all relevant setters/getters.

[image: Business Entity UML Diagram]

The `entityType` property is an integer which represents a foreign key (FK) relationship to a reference table containing all of the possible entity types (corporation, LLC, sole prop, etc...). Here's what the database diagram looks like:

[image: database relationship model]

When populating the `Business` entity from a CRUD read() method, it automatically grabs the proper `entityTypeName` through an INNER JOIN in the DAO (data access object) and sets it via `setEntityTypeName()`.  This process makes sense to me and seems pretty standard as far as I know.

However, lets say you have a web form where a user can edit the `Business` entity object.  The user fills out a form where they can edit the business name and entity type based on a select box of available options (populated from the reference table).

[image: web form example]

When the user submits the form, the data is validated and then a service object executes `setBusinessName()` with the value from the form.  Next, it executes `setEntityType()` and populates the integer value from the entity type select box.  **At this point in time, the `entityTypeName` may or may not be valid** (if the user changed it, for example).

There are a couple ways I can think of to solve for this:

1. The same form service, after executing `setEntityType()` would immediately execute `setEntityTypeName()` afterwards and populate the right value. (easiest method I think since the validation process would retrieve the correct entity type name)
2. The `Business` entity's `setEntityType()` method contains business logic to automatically populate the `entityTypeName` property through some type of injected dependency (service) which would look up the data and assign it.  (this seems like a more DDD approach) and would make the `Business` entity object require a lot more behavior and dependencies (services, etc...).

What is the proper way to solve this type of situation?  Obviously this is a simple example, but in an actual data model, there could be TONS of reference fields like `entityType` which would require behavior like this.

Edit: Grammar fixes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You wouldn't.

It looks like you are mixing UI requirements into your domain model. Use dedicated view models for presenting data, your domain models should only come into play when stuff gets done.

I would suggest that `EntityTypeName` does not belong in `Business`. `EntityType` is its own aggregate root and `Business` probably only needs a reference to the `EntityType.Id`.

Your setter can be changed to:

```
SetEntityType(EntityType entity) {
   //Any rules here based on entity?
  entityTypeId = entityType.GetId();
}
```

Comment: Very interesting and I appreciate the insight.  I'm pretty new to DDD concepts but am I correct to assume that you propose having a different object any time I need to use business data in some type of UI/presentation (e.g. `BusinessView`)?   Am I also correct that in order to create the `BusinessView` object, I should use something called an "anti-corruption" layer to transform a `Business` object into a `BusinessView` object?

Comment: Don't treat DDD as a fancy ORM/DataLayer with logic. At the risk of sounding airy-fairy its more of a philosophy and a collection of practices,  patterns and processed than a follow-the-instructions-do-thing-x-like-this.
Depending on the complexity of your model, it *may* be worth having a separate view model for lists (search results) and displays - Don't let your UI dictate your domain model, this is what separation of concerns is all about. 
Anti-Corruption layer are domain specified interfaces to existing systems that you cant or dont want to change.

Comment: If we take a step back and look at the problem from a contemporary OOP perspective (forgetting about DDD for the moment), how would you solve the problem?  Would you still use a separate `BusinessView` object or do something else?

Comment: In this simplified use case for "Edit A Business" I would not need a separate view model. My EditBusiess page needs the single Business object and a list of all available EntityType objects. The UI page would populate the entity type drop down with the ids and names of the entitytypes and the form post back would send back a view model with the new business name and entitytype id. HOWEVER, the preceeding 'Select a business to edit' page would proably contain a filterable list that resolves the business entity type to its name, This would be a seperate viewModel